# How to properly configure timestamp handling for TIMESTAMP columns in Hibernate6/Spring Boot 3.0?

Tags: java, spring, oracle, hibernate, hibernate-6.x

We're currently migrating a Spring Boot 2 application to Spring Boot 3 (`3.0.2`) which includes moving to Hibernate 6 (`6.1.6`).

All Timestamps are normalized to UTC and saved to the underlying OracleDB using columns of the TIMESTAMP data type (without timezones). To make Hibernate use UTC we set the `jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.time_zone` configuration property to `true` within our `application.yaml`.

After moving to Spring Boot 3 and Hibernate 6 (which introduces a more specific configuration for timestamp conversion) the migration of timestamps doesn't work as expected anymore:

When looking up entities by timestamp attributes, they won't be found.

**A short example:**
Saving an entity with a `java.time.Instant` timestamp of `2023-12-13T00:00:00Z` to the database creates a new record as expected.
However, when trying to retrieve the record using the same timestamp the data repository will return an empty result. It therefore seems that the timestamp conversion differs between saving and querying.

We tried to adjust this behaviour using the configuration property `spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.timezone.default_storage` but no matter what value we set, the behaviour kept being the same. We also tried different combinations of the `jdbc.time_zone` and `timezone.default_storage` config properties without recognizing any effects on the application's behaviour. We initially thought that the properties for whatever reason wouldn't be applied, but assigning invalid values raised exceptions on application startup.

The same code works like a charm when using a H2 database.

The relevant part of the `application.yaml` we're using is as follows:

```
spring:
  datasource:
    driverClassName: oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
    url: jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe
    username: [dbuser]
    password: [dbpassword]
    type: org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.SimpleDriverDataSource
  jpa:
    show-sql: false
    generate-ddl: true
    hibernate.ddl-auto: none
    task:
    scheduling:
      pool:
        size: 10
    properties:
      hibernate:
        jdbc:
          time_zone: UTC
        timezone:
          default_storage: NORMALIZE_UTC
```

An example entity:

```
import jakarta.persistence.Column;
import jakarta.persistence.Entity;
import jakarta.persistence.Id;
import jakarta.persistence.Table;
import java.time.Instant;
import java.util.UUID;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;

@Setter
@Getter
@Entity
@Table(name ="entity")
public class DemoEntity {

  @Id
  @Column(name = "`id`")
  UUID id;

  @Column(name = "`demo_timestamp`" ,columnDefinition = "TIMESTAMP")
  private Instant timestamp;

  public DemoEntity() {
    this.id = UUID.randomUUID();
  }

}
```

The repository:

```
import java.time.Instant;
import java.util.Optional;
import java.util.UUID;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaSpecificationExecutor;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository
public interface EntityRepository extends JpaRepository<DemoEntity, UUID>, JpaSpecificationExecutor<DemoEntity> {

  Optional<DemoEntity> findAllByTimestamp(Instant timestamp);
}
```

The service showcasing the observed behaviour:

```
import java.time.Instant;
import java.util.Optional;
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.event.ContextRefreshedEvent;
import org.springframework.context.event.EventListener;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

@Service
@Slf4j
public class EntityService {

  private final EntityRepository repository;

  @Autowired
  public EntityService(EntityRepository repository) {
    this.repository = repository;
  }

  @EventListener(ContextRefreshedEvent.class)
  @Transactional
  public void init() {
    Instant timestamp = Instant.parse("2022-12-31T23:00:00Z");

    Optional<DemoEntity> findResult = repository.findAllByTimestamp(timestamp);

    if(findResult.isPresent()) {
      log.info("Entity was found for timestamp {}", timestamp);
      return;
    }

    log.info("No entity was found for timestamp {}, creating one", timestamp);

    DemoEntity demoEntity = new DemoEntity();
    demoEntity.setTimestamp(timestamp);

    this.repository.save(demoEntity);
  }
}
```

The service keeps creating new records with correct timestamps since it fails to look up the persisted timestamps:

1. **The entity is created properly...**
   [image]
2. **...but not found by the SQL query afterwards...**

```
2023-01-26T07:20:47.986+01:00  INFO 1274 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http) with context path ''
2023-01-26T07:20:48.105+01:00 DEBUG 1274 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.SQL                        : select d1_0."id",d1_0."demo_timestamp" from entity d1_0 where d1_0."demo_timestamp"=?
2023-01-26T07:20:48.106+01:00 TRACE 1274 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.orm.jdbc.bind              : binding parameter [1] as [TIMESTAMP_UTC] - [2022-12-31T23:00:00Z]
2023-01-26T07:20:48.130+01:00  INFO 1274 --- [  restartedMain] com.example.demo.EntityService           : No entity was found for timestamp 2022-12-31T23:00:00Z, creating one
2023-01-26T07:20:48.138+01:00 DEBUG 1274 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.SQL                        : select d1_0."id",d1_0."demo_timestamp" from entity d1_0 where d1_0."id"=?
2023-01-26T07:20:48.138+01:00 TRACE 1274 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.orm.jdbc.bind              : binding parameter [1] as [BINARY] - [1ccd9b88-4d18-416a-938d-d8c3fb6dac7d]
2023-01-26T07:20:48.150+01:00 DEBUG 1274 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.SQL                        : insert into entity ("demo_timestamp", "id") values (?, ?)
2023-01-26T07:20:48.150+01:00 TRACE 1274 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.orm.jdbc.bind              : binding parameter [1] as [TIMESTAMP_UTC] - [2022-12-31T23:00:00Z]
2023-01-26T07:20:48.150+01:00 TRACE 1274 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.orm.jdbc.bind              : binding parameter [2] as [BINARY] - [1ccd9b88-4d18-416a-938d-d8c3fb6dac7d]
```

3. **...resulting in another entity being created**
   [image]

We also found, that looking up the entities as if they were in fact using not UTC but our local timezone CET, i.e. UTC+1, delivered the expected results. More specifically, looking up records for an Instant of `2022-31-12T22:00:00Z` returned the entities having a timestamp of `2022-31-12T23:00:00Z`. Moreover everything works fine when setting the JVM timezone using `TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));` or `-Duser.timezone=UTC`.

It seems that UTC timestamps represented as Instants are actually converted to local time when being queried but are handled properly when being written to the database.

Do we miss anything in our configuration or is there a bug in Spring/Hibernate that causes this odd behaviour?

As far as I know the default behaviour of Hibernate 6 should match the one provided by version 5 so that no configuration changes should be required at all to preserve the previous behaviour.

Comment: I would like to help you with this one, but I can't because the critical code which actually sets the query parameter is hidden from me. I have no clue what `findAllByTimestamp()` does.  So if you can reproduce the problem *with just Hibernate* and no Spring repository, I'll be able to help.

Comment: You should look at the Hibernate generated SQL and the values passed, and at the presentation from Oracle Office Hours: https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/asktom.search?oh=19484 from time 53:00, it's about DATE and TIMESTAMP and how ORACLE is handling TZ and daylight saving.

Comment: FTR I just wrote and tested some code which does what you want to do in pure Hibernate, and it worked with no issues. So the problem would seem to be in whatever Spring is doing that is hidden from me.

Comment: Thank you for your input. I updated the question to include some screenshots of the DB table and the associated log statements that contain the generated sql and parameter bindings.

@p3consulting since no changes were made to the database itself or the way we handle time zones I suspect that the issue resides somewehere in the Spring/Hibernate layer. Thank you anyway for sharing the video, it gave some interesting insights into Oracle's timestamp handling.

Comment: @Gavin Basically, `findAllByTimestamp` uses Spring's aut-generation mechanism for creating the SQL query provided by the logs. However, I also tried explicitly defining a native query (`select * from entity where demo_timestamp = :timestamp`) which caused no differences. Thanks for your input using plain Hibernate, maybe there is an issue with Spring's communication with JPA/Hibernate. I'll have a shot at this for myself to gain more insights!

Comment: @TobsenB what is the version of JDBC driver? Does annotating timestamp field by `@JdbcType(InstantAsTimestampJdbcType.class)` change behaviour?

Comment: @Andrey We're using ojdbc10@19.16.0.0. Adding `@JdbcType(InstantAsTimestampJdbcType.class)` to the field actually fixes the behaviour. Unfortunately, although this would fix the symptoms for every field using the annotation it would not resolve the problem itself.

Comment: @TobsenB `InstantAsTimestampJdbcType` behaves like HBN5 did: it converts `Instant` to `Timestamp` prior sending data to JDBC driver, `InstantAsTimestampWithTimeZoneJdbcType` type, which is default for HBN6/Oracle, works differently: it converts `Instant` to `OffsetDateTime` (there are some issues on JDBC 4.2 spec side related to `Instant` type) prior sending data to JDBC driver. As I can see ojdbc versions `19.16.0.0` and `21.8.0.0` handle `OffsetDateTime` differently, that could be a reason.

Comment: so, you have three options: 1. place `@JdbcType(InstantAsTimestampJdbcType.class)` over `Instant` fields. 2. Tune dialect in HBN: I believe that is enough to implement SPI `org.hibernate.boot.model.TypeContributor` with smth. like `typeContributions.contributeJdbcType(InstantAsTimestampJdbcType.class)`. 3. Try newer version of JDBC driver.

Comment: @Andrey Thank you for your contributions, I'll check the provided solutions!

Answer (score 2):

OK, so, look, after my comment I was really hoping that you would make an attempt to reproduce the problem outside of Spring, so that we could establish what the cause of it is.

But anyway, I have now I've managed to reproduce it with the following setup:

1. set the JVM timezone to `EST` and the Oracle server timezone to `UTC`
2. *do not set* `hibernate.jdbc.time_zone`, so that Hibernate doesn't know there's a mismatch between the timezones
3. manually override the default column type generated by Hibernate's schema export from `timestamp with time zone` to `timestamp`, using the JPA `@Column` annotation
4. *do not set* `hibernate.type.preferred_instant_jdbc_type`, nor use `@JdbcTypeCode(TIMESTAMP)`, so that Hibernate doesn't know you're using a local `timestamp` as your column type
5. finally, *and most importantly*, use `setParameter("timestamp", Timestamp.from(instant))` when binding the parameter of the query, instead of just passing the `Instant` object

FTR, the test code I have used is the following:

```java
@DomainModel(annotatedClasses = UTCNormalizedInstantTest.Instantaneous.class)
@SessionFactory
@ServiceRegistry(settings = {@Setting(name = AvailableSettings.TIMEZONE_DEFAULT_STORAGE, value = "NORMALIZE_UTC"),
//      @Setting(name = AvailableSettings.JDBC_TIME_ZONE, value="UTC"),
//      @Setting(name = AvailableSettings.PREFERRED_INSTANT_JDBC_TYPE, value="TIMESTAMP")
})
public class UTCNormalizedInstantTest {

    @Test
    void test(SessionFactoryScope scope) {
        TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone("EST"));
        Instant timestamp = Instant.parse("2022-12-31T23:00:00Z");
        UUID id = scope.fromTransaction( s-> {
            Instantaneous z = new Instantaneous();
            z.instant = timestamp;
            s.persist(z);
            return z.id;
        });
        scope.inSession( s-> {
            Instantaneous z = s.find(Instantaneous.class, id);
            assertEquals( timestamp, z.instant );
        });
        scope.inSession( s-> {
            Instant i = s.createQuery("select i.instant from Instantaneous i", Instant.class)
                    .getSingleResult();
            assertEquals( timestamp, i );
            Instantaneous a = s.createQuery("from Instantaneous i where i.instant=:timestamp", Instantaneous.class)
                    .setParameter("timestamp", timestamp )
                    .getSingleResult();
            assertEquals( timestamp, a.instant );
            Instantaneous b = s.createQuery("from Instantaneous i where cast(i.instant as Timestamp)=:timestamp", Instantaneous.class)
                    .setParameter("timestamp", Timestamp.from(timestamp) )
                    .getSingleResult();
            assertEquals( timestamp, b.instant );
        });
    }

    @Entity(name = "Instantaneous")
    public static class Instantaneous {
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue
        UUID id;
//      @JdbcTypeCode(Types.TIMESTAMP)
        @Column(columnDefinition = "timestamp")
        Instant instant;
    }
}
```

Now, uncommenting *any one* of the three commented lines, or removing the `@Column` annotation makes this test pass.

So the solution is, either:

- set `hibernate.type.preferred_instant_jdbc_type=TIMESTAMP`,
- annotate the field `@JdbcTypeCode(TIMESTAMP)`, or
- set `hibernate.jdbc.time_zone` to the server time zone (you say you tried this but I'm willing to bet that if you debug you'll find it didn't stick).

Note that I was *only* able to eventually reproduce the problem by using `setParameter("timestamp", Timestamp.from(instant))`. It does not appear to occur if I use `setParameter("timestamp", instant)`, which of course better and more natural. This makes sense. I suppose (but do not know) that if you debug the code generated by Spring, you will find that it is (incorrectly) converting your `Instant` to a `Timestamp` before passing it to `setParameter()`.

FTR, the difference between H5 and H6 is that by default H6 uses a `timestamp with time zone` to store `Instant`s, rather than a `timestamp`, since a `timestamp` with no time zone is more like a Java `LocalDateTime`. Since you're using `timestamp` to store your `Instant`, you need to let Hibernate know about that, or, at the very least, let it know about the mismatch between the JVM and Oracle time zones.

Comment: Actually, I did and also found that the issue is not present when using hibernate only. Thank you for your investigation on the topic. What I read from your description is that it should work with the configuration we use since we set `hibernate.jdbc.time_zone` in the `application.yaml`. However, I agree with you that this configuration property (which formerly used to work) seems not to be applied properly on our Spring Boot 3.0 branch. Since we didn't change the configuration  and it should be still valid according to the Spring documentation there might be an issue in Spring

Comment: Well, before blaming Spring, I think you should debug the code to see exactly what’s happening. I tried as many permutations of everything as I could think of, but it’s always possible I missed something.

Answer (score 0):

`Hibernate 5` was using [following method](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/49fbe84dde773de84ea704bb10193c4c581d34b8/hibernate-core/src/main/java/org/hibernate/type/descriptor/sql/TimestampTypeDescriptor.java#L81) to perform all date/time related calculations:

```java
@Override
protected X doExtract(ResultSet rs, String name, WrapperOptions options) throws SQLException {
  return options.getJdbcTimeZone() != null ?
   javaTypeDescriptor.wrap( rs.getTimestamp( name, Calendar.getInstance( options.getJdbcTimeZone() ) ), options ) :
   javaTypeDescriptor.wrap( rs.getTimestamp( name ), options );
}
```

Now, for your "Instant case", `Hibernate 6` uses [following method](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/cc42864351ab571cd1b85347fdc323764a35fa30/hibernate-core/src/main/java/org/hibernate/type/descriptor/jdbc/InstantAsTimestampWithTimeZoneJdbcType.java#L88):

```java
protected void doBind(
        PreparedStatement st,
        X value,
        int index,
        WrapperOptions wrapperOptions) throws SQLException {
    final OffsetDateTime dateTime = javaType.unwrap( value, OffsetDateTime.class, wrapperOptions );
    // supposed to be supported in JDBC 4.2
    st.setObject( index, dateTime.withOffsetSameInstant( ZoneOffset.UTC ), Types.TIMESTAMP_WITH_TIMEZONE );
}
```

which actually looks weird because HBN binds timezone-aware data-type to non-timezone-aware column and the question is: what does the expression `st.setObject(index, odt, 2014)` really mean and what actual value will DB engine use when selecting rows?

Answer:

- JDBC driver sends "expected" value
- DB engine adjusts both date/time data stored in table and query parameters to UTC timezone (for stored data it uses [session timezone](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions176.htm#SQLRF06105) as a baseline - `ALTER SESSION SET TIME_ZONE='UTC'` solve the issue as well as setting JDK timezone to `UTC`) prior doing any comparisons (that is the reason why your select statement does not return data) - that actually becomes clear if we take a look at execution plan:

```
explain plan for
select * from entity
where "demo_timestamp" = to_timestamp_tz(:1);

select plan_table_output
from table(dbms_xplan.display('plan_table',null,'basic +predicate'));
```

```
Explained.


PLAN_TABLE_OUTPUT                                           
------------------------------------------------------------
Plan hash value: 92196100
 
------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation         | Name   |
------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT  |        |
|*  1 |  TABLE ACCESS FULL| ENTITY |
------------------------------------
 
Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

PLAN_TABLE_OUTPUT                                           
------------------------------------------------------------
 
   1 - filter(SYS_EXTRACT_UTC(INTERNAL_FUNCTION("demo_timest
amp"))=SYS_EXTRACT_UTC(TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ(:1)))

14 rows selected.
```

So, yes, there are "breaking changes" (or a bug) in `Hibernate 6` and now storing timezone-aware data in non-timezone-aware columns may cause a plenty of issues (wrong results, slow queries, etc)